# Remove value from first array that exists in the second array

Tags: javascript

I have this variable:

```
var first = [{name: "john", key: "1"}, 
             {name: "george", key: "3"}, 
             {name: "paul", key: "2"},
             {name: "ringo", key: "4"}];

var second = [{key: "2"}, 
              {key: "4"}, 
              {key: "3"}]
```

I am trying to create a new object that omits value that is missing at `second`, in this case, `name: "john"`:

```
var third = [{name: "george", key: "3"}, 
             {name: "paul", key: "2"},
             {name: "ringo", key: "4"}];
```

Here's the code I tried:

```
var third = first.map(obj => {
    var retVal = {};
    retVal["name"] = obj.name;
    retVal["key"] = obj.key;
    return retVal;
});
```

This code adds all and becomes:

```
var third = [{name: "john", key: "1"}, 
             {name: "george", key: "3"}, 
             {name: "paul", key: "2"},
             {name: "ringo", key: "4"}];
```

, but can't figure out the restriction that wouldn't add the one I want to omit.

Please note, that regular loop is not a deal, it has to be with `.map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the functions `filter`, `map` and `includes` as follow:

```js
var first  = [{name: "john", key: "1"},             {name: "george", key: "3"},             {name: "paul", key: "2"},{name: "ringo", key: "4"}],
    second = [{key: "2"}, {key: "4"}, {key: "3"}],
    keys   = second.map(o => o.key),
    result = first.filter(o => keys.includes(o.key));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @guautemoczihuataneho great!!

Comment: @guautemoczihuataneho you can upvote any time you want, the wait is only imposed on *accepting* ;-)